# Concatenating two arrays results in two modified arrays instead of one C#

Tags: c#, arrays, concatenation

I have a very strange Behavior when merging two arrays together:

#### Assumptions

I have a class `Tensor` which contains an array `float[]` and a function AddTensorElements:

```
class Tensor
{
    public float[] MovingAverage3h { get; set; }
    public float[] MovingAverage6h { get; set; }
    public float[] MovingAverage1d { get; set; }
    public void AddTensorElements(Tensor input)
    {
        if (this.MovingAverage3h == null)
        this.MovingAverage3h = input.MovingAverage3h;
        this.MovingAverage6h = input.MovingAverage6h;
        this.MovingAverage1d = input.MovingAverage1d;
        }
        else
       {
       this.MovingAverage3h = Concat(this.MovingAverage3h, input.MovingAverage6h);
       this.MovingAverage6h = Concat(this.MovingAverage6h, input.MovingAverage6h);
       this.MovingAverage1d = Concat(this.MovingAverage1d, input.MovingAverage1d);
       }
    private float[] Concat (float[] first, float[] second)
    {
        List<float> concatenated = new List<float>();
        concatenated.AddRange(first);
        concatenated.AddRange(second);
        //foreach (float value in first) concatenated.Add(value);
        //foreach (float value in second) concatenated.Add(value);
        float[] returnArray = concatenated.ToArray();
        return returnArray;
    }
}
```

Within my main program, I repeatedly add the tensor `M6t` to the base tensor `Minutes30[i]`

```
class TensorCreator
{

    private static List<Elements.Tensor> Minutes30 = new List<Elements.Tensor>();

    private static void AddValues(Tensor M6t)
    {
        // Fill Minutes 30
        Minutes30.Add(M6t);
        for (int i = CounterM30; i < Minutes30.Count-1; i += M6)
        {
            { } // Issue come up right here
            Minutes30[i].AddTensorElements(M6t);
            { } // Issue come up right here
        }
    }
    public static void AppendDataToTensor(Elements.Tensor queueElement)
    {
        // ...
        AddValues(M6Avg);
    }
}
```

#### Expected behavior vs actual behavior

The array within `Minutes[i]` expands
The array within `M6t` stays`float[1]`

So far so good, this works in a tiny separate test application

Within my actual application, the same code lets the baseTensor expand but also the input tensor gets expanded!

```
for (int i = CounterM30; i < Minutes30.Count-1; i += M6)
{
    // M6T.Length == 1;
    Minutes30[i].AddTensorElements(M6t);
    // M6T.Length == Minutes30[i].Length;
}
```

strangely, whitin `AddtensorToElements()` I can see the values changing as well:
[image]

Comment: `List<>.AddRange` will make your life easier.

Comment: same result. as I have written.

Comment: I didn't say it would fix your problem.

Comment: can you share the actual reproducible code? I can understand your test code, but don't know what are you talking later.

Comment: The Issue is that the Code is pretty long but Ill have a Try,

Comment: Can you remove all previous description but only shows what the problem is in your reproducible code? and in your reproducible code, you don't need to show all calls, but simply 2-3 calls are enough to show issues. correct?

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience, i managed to add you edits now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue lies right here:

```
Minutes30.Add(M6t);
```

This adds a reference of Class Tensor M6t to Minutes 30. The result is that Minutes30[i] gets concatenated with it self.

Solution:
In class Tensor, add a `Clone()` method

```
public Tensor Clone()
{
    Tensor tensor = new Tensor();
    tensor.MovingAverage3h = this.MovingAverage3h.ToArray();
    tensor.MovingAverage6h = this.MovingAverage6h.ToArray();
    tensor.MovingAverage1d = this.MovingAverage1d.ToArray();
    return tensor;
}
```

then change

```
    Minutes30.Add(M6t);
```

to

```
    Minutes30.Add(M6t.Clone());
```